# How to include files from another repo in Jekyll build?

Tags: bash, git, jekyll

When I run this, files changes from the copied `/first-repo` are being ignored by `bundle exec`. How can I make sure that the files from `/first-repo` are included?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /first-repo;
git pull;

cd /second-repo;
git pull;

# copy folder from first repo to second repo
cp -rf /first-repo /second-repo/destination_folder;

git add -A;
git commit -m "update destination folder from first repo";
git push;

# build 
bundle exec rake build_site;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a [Git Submodule](https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255).

Continuing the example, in `second-repo` you can instantiate a git submodule of `first-repo` to get the whole `first-repo` repository as a directory inside `second-repo`. You can also use the [Jekyll config `include`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) variable to specify what files from `first-repo` to use in `second-repo`.

Comment: What if your jekyll repo is a submodule of this repo? How does `git clone --recursive` handle loops?